# CollectionViewCell out of screen on iphone 5

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have this custom UICollectionViewCell and it works nice on iphone 7, but when I run it on Iphone 5 simulator, things are acting weird.
My collection view has many sections and one item per section. It looks like a table view, meaning each cell is full width and they are all above each other like in a table view.
For some reason in Iphone 5 the frame is: (-27.5, 50.0, 320.0, 45.7143)
meaning it is in the correct width and height, but it starts 27.5 points to the left of the screen. I update the cell like this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> ProfileCollectionCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionCell
    let width = CGFloat((self.collectionView?.frame.width)!)
    let height = width/7
    cell.frame.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    return cell
}
```

how can i have the frame positioned correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't set the cell's frame in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Instead, implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method…

```
func collectionView(UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath) {
    let width = collectionView?.frame.width ?? 0
    let height = width / 7
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first add protocol into your class `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and add below code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
   let width = CGFloat((self.collectionView?.frame.width)!)
   let height = width/7
   return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```